# Setting map region based on current location

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, expo

i would really appreciate some help with this issue.

Basically i am trying to pass my current latitude and longtitude via var1 and var2 into the coordinates of the initial region. However, upon running this code there will be an error message stating that **Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `initialRegion.latitude` is marked as required in `MapView`, but its value is `undefined`.**

I have printed out the value of var1 and var2 to console and it can be seen that they are numbers and are definitely not undefined. Can someone please **kindly** explain to me what is going on and recommend a solution?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import  MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {
      region : 
      {
        latitude: 1.290270,
        longitude: 103.851959,
        latitudeDelta: 0.02,
        longitudeDelta: 0.02,
      },
      location: null,
      errorMessage : null,

    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && !Constants.isDevice) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!',
      });
    } else {
      this._getLocationAsync();
    }
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
      });
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    this.setState({ location });
  };

  render() {
    let text = 'Waiting..';
    if (this.state.errorMessage) {
      text = this.state.errorMessage;
    } else if (this.state.location) {
      var1 = (this.state.location.coords.latitude);
      var2 = (this.state.location.coords.longitude);
      console.log(var1);
      console.log(var2 +" "+typeof(var2));

    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{this.var1, this.var2}</Text>
        <MapView 
        style={styles.mapStyle}  
        initialRegion={{latitude: this.var1,longitude: this.var2, latitudeDelta:0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02}}
        >
            <Marker
              coordinate={{latitude: 1.290270, longitude: 103.851959}}
              title={'Singapore'}
              description={'Sg505'}
            />
        </MapView> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  mapStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined these `var1` and `var2` variables. You could define them as class variables (Thus accessing them with `this.var1` would work), however it makes more sense to define them directly on the `render` function.

Also, where you print their values, the `Text` component expects a string child, where you pass two strings. So, it would be better to join those two strings, either with `var1 + var2`, or `` `${var1}${var2}` ``

```js
  render() {
    let var1;
    let var2;
    let text = 'Waiting..';
    if (this.state.errorMessage) {
      text = this.state.errorMessage;
    } else if (this.state.location) {
      var1 = (this.state.location.coords.latitude);
      var2 = (this.state.location.coords.longitude);
      console.log(var1);
      console.log(var2 +" "+typeof(var2));

    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{`${var1} ${var2}`}</Text>
        <MapView 
        style={styles.mapStyle}  
        initialRegion={{latitude: var1, longitude: var2, latitudeDelta:0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02}}
        >
            <Marker
              coordinate={{latitude: 1.290270, longitude: 103.851959}}
              title={'Singapore'}
              description={'Sg505'}
            />
        </MapView> 
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks so much !! it allowed me to set the region however it is still displaying a warning saying that the value is undefined although the map is being loaded and at the right region? also why is it that when i replace the values in the marker "  coordinate={{latitude: 1.290270, longitude: 103.851959}}" with var1 and var 2 i get the error Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `initialRegion.latitude` is marked as required in `MapView`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: @YeoBryan I just noticed, you are only setting `var1` and `var2` when the `location` state variable is truthy. Since it starts as `null`, if it isn't updated, `var1` and `var2` won't be set. If the `region` state is for the current region of the map, you can use it to define `var1` and `var2`, at least while `location` is `null`.